# Normalizing complex number between two values matlab

Tags: matlab, double, complex-numbers, normalize

I have a 3D matrix of complex double. I want to normalize the whole matrix (both imaginary and real) into the range from -0.5 to 0.5. So I tried

```
newMatrix = normalize( oldMatrix, 'range', [-0.5,0.5] )
```

But this error comes

```
Undefined function 'normalize' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Could anyone tell me how to normalize complex double into the range please? Thanks a lot!

Edit: I am in R2017b MATLAB. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @rahnema1 , but the same error still occur.

Comment: The function `normalize` that you're trying to use has been introduced in the release R2018a (see [help page](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/normalize.html#d119e785557)). Are you sure you have that release?

Comment: thanks @MassimoOrtolano, my MATLAB is R2017b....  Do you have any ways to normalize it with R2017b please?

Comment: `normalize` doesn't support complex arrays.  Btw it is a bit unclear how you intend to normalize. i.e. whether one 3D slice is dependent on the other for normalization or not, are both real and imag values considered simultaneously while normalization or are they separately considered and then joined together.? An example of  a sample 3D matrix alongwith the expected output would clear things up.  Mathematics of manually normalising are not too hard to do. You can make a try and update with it and we'll see how it goes.